# Get `the input device is not a TTY` error when run docker command inside a while loop

Tags: bash, docker, tty, pty

I have below bash script. It run `docker run` command inside a while loop which read from a text file line by line.

```
#!/bin/sh -eu

while IFS= read -r url; do
    docker run --rm -it alpine ls
done < repo_list.txt
```

I get this error `the input device is not a TTY` when executing the above script. However, it works fine if I remove the `while loop` like this:

```
#!/bin/sh -eu
docker run --rm -it alpine ls
```

I know that I can fix it by removing the `-it` parameter from the docker command. But I'd like to know why the `while loop` cause this error. Is there any way I can fix it without changing the docker command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second example, you forgot to change stdin like you've done in your while loop:

```
< repo_list.txt
```

With input as a file, you cannot enable interactive and tty support simultaneously, because the file is not a tty device.